# Java HTTP Library

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I'm currently using this Java Http Library: http://kevinsawicki.github.io/http-request/

So basically what I have now is this,

```
HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.get(url);
```

I have a custom object called HttpResult which contains the ResponseCode and ResponseBody, so what I need to do is to return the object like this:

```
return new HttpResult(req.code(), req.body());
```

But the problem is, the code() method and body() method in this HTTP library executes the GET request everytime it is called, so in order for me to return my own object with the response code and body, I am making a GET request twice.

How do I get the Response Code and Response Body of the HTTP request and only execute the request ONCE?

Comment: Why must the response contain all the request data?  Shouldn't that be what's generated by the request?  Shouldn't the GET request return an HttpResult?

Comment: If you look at the link of the library (http://kevinsawicki.github.io/http-request/), the get() method returns the HttpRequest object, which we are supposed to use code() to get the Response Code, and body() to get the Response Body. 

That's why I'm asking if anyone familiar knows how to get both Code and Body together in one GET request.

Comment: Sounds like a badly written library.  Why did you choose it?  I'd check out Apache Commons HTTP.

Comment: @duffymo I agree with you : there is no reason to generate more HTTP calls upon getters. Also seems this lib does not respect Java coding standards having getters not beginning with 'get'.

Comment: I'll bet you can find examples in the JDK as well.   Not sacrosant.